# How to create a button that won't move on a responsive website?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to put a button background image.
The problem is that when I try to reduce and increase the screen, it moves and does not stay in place
Is there a possibility that it won't move when I decrease and increase the screen?
[image]

```
    <div className="main_giftcard">
      <div className="giftcard">
        <Container className="contact-content debug-border">
          <Col>
            <button class="button-69" role="button">
              Click he re to buy
            </button>
          </Col>
        </Container>
      </div>
   
    </div>
```

```
.main_giftcard {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(../../data/image/giftcard/bn.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.giftcard {
  position: absolute;

  bottom: 20%;
  right: 33%;
}
.button-69 {
  display: block;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */

  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ffbf01 0, #ffbf01 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: rgba(245, 244, 247, 0.25) 0 1px 1px inset;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.03, 0.35, 1);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 190px;
}

The button moves for me to zoom in and out of the screen
```

Comment: Why are you using an image for the text? Just write the text above the button and there will be no overlaps.

Comment: This is a banner I made with a picture on the side

Comment: When you say 'won't move' what exactly do you want it to do/where is it to be? Is it to be in the same position in relation to the image regardless of the aspect ratio of the viewport? If so you need to position it in relation to the whole image e.g. in % terms.

Comment: One solution would be to set a `margin-top` value. Give it a Top-margin that works and add media queries for different resolutions should you need that.